# retrieve rows of 1st column based on common data on 2nd column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have input like this:

```
1st column ---------2nd column
23 ---------------------- 0080
23 ---------------------- 0010
23 ---------------------- 0080
25 ---------------------- 0010
25 ---------------------- 0010
34 ---------------------- 0080
27 ---------------------- 0010
27 ---------------------- 0080
```

I want to retrieve all the rows of 1st column which has both 0080 and 0010 data in 2nd column.
result will be like this:

```
1st column--------- 2nd column
23 ---------------------- 0080
23 ---------------------- 0010
23 ---------------------- 0080
27 ---------------------- 0010
27 ---------------------- 0080
```

From result we can see that 1st column doesn't include 25 as 25 has only 0010 in 2nd column, and same for 34 which has only 0080 in 2nd column.

I tried using nested query, but it is becoming very slow as my table is very large (contains around 30,000+ rows). I am looking for smart technique which is faster for large data table.

Comment: selecting distinct 1st columns and checking 2nd with where seems the only reasonable solution to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where col1 in 
(
   select col1
   from your_table
   where col2 in ('0080', '0010')
   group by col1
   having count(distinct col2) = 2
)
```

Comment: This returns only one row per col1 value, not all as required

Answer (score 0):

```
select first
from t
where second in ('0080', '0010')
group by first
having count(distinct second) = 2
```

Comment: This also returns only one row per col1 value, not all as required.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.Col1,t.Col2
  FROM dbo.YourTable t
  JOIN(
    SELECT Col1, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN Col2 = '0010' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Has0010,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Col2 = '0080' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Has0080
      FROM dbo.YourTable
      GROUP BY Col1
  )FilterTbl f
  ON t.Col1 = f.Col1 AND f.Has0010 = 1 AND f.Has0080 = 1
```